# Whenever I try to download my Ubuntu 1 files, chrome block me.

Tags: files, storage

I received an email regarding the closure of ubuntu1 files I tried using the link to transfer (os is Windows 7 Ultimate) each time I tried I received error message Chrome blocked download, is MALICIOUS.

I can't even remember how to view my files to see if any could be removed. Please let me know what are my alternatives in retrieving my files.

Comment: Use firefox instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another browser? Chrome frequently blocks "bad" stuff, and is normally right (which is why I use it) but it can be wrong.

Or you could transfer them to Google Drive / Skydrive / Dropbox? I received the same email, and they suggest going to [mover.io](https://mover.io/connectors/ubuntu-one/) as they offer it for free for Ubuntu 1 at the moment.

Comment: You could have commented that.

Comment: @Raphael If it works, surely it's an answer / solution?